# Rendering deeply nested json as table in React

Tags: json, reactjs, nested

I'm working on a sports app and I've been having a hell of a time trying to render a league standings table in React (15.5.4).

What's so confusing is that I have a stats table for an individual team which renders perfectly, and as far as I can tell the data for team stats has the exact same structure and the same number of nesting levels as the league stats:

```
[
  {
    teamID: whatever,
    Tables: [
      {
        Columns: [
          {
            Title: columnheader
          }
        ],
        Rows: [
          {
            Cells: [
              {
                Value: blah 
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code (that works for team stats):

```
 <div className="statsTableContainer">
      <Tabs style={tabContainerStyles}>
        {gameStatsTable.map((team) =>
          <Tab key={team.Label} label={team.Label} style={tabStyles}>
            {team.Tables.map((table, idx) =>
              <Table
                key={`table-${idx}`}
                selectable={false}
                multiSelectable={false}
                style={{
                  background: 'none',
                }}
              >
                <TableHeader
                  displaySelectAll={false}
                  adjustForCheckbox={false}
                >
                  <TableRow>
                    {table.Columns.map((column, idx2) =>
                      <TableHeaderColumn
                        key={`column-${idx2}`}
                        style={{...columnStyle, width: `${idx2 === 0 ? '30px' : '15px'}`, textAlign: `${idx2 === 0 ? 'left' : 'center'}`}}
                      >
                        {column.Title}
                      </TableHeaderColumn>
                    )}
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody
                  displayRowCheckbox={false}
                >
                  {table.Rows.map((row, idx3) =>
                    <TableRow key={`row-${idx3}`} style={{ color: 'white' }}>
                      {row.Cells.map((cell, idx4) =>
                        <TableRowColumn key={`cell-${idx4}`} style={{
                          ...columnStyle,
                          width: `${idx4 === 0 ? '30px' : '15px'}`,
                          textAlign: `${idx4 === 0 ? 'left' : 'center'}`,
                          color: `${cell.Highlight ? 'yellow' : 'white'}`,
                        }}>{cell.Value}</TableRowColumn>
                      )}
                    </TableRow>
                  )}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            )}
          </Tab>
        )}
      </Tabs>     
    </div>
```

But for some reason, when it comes to league stats, it works up to mapping the columns and rows, but breaks on trying to render a row's cells.  The specific error I'm getting is 'undefined is not an object: row.Cells.map'.  What am I not seeing?

For reference, here is the data url for standings (not mapping to table properly): https://us-central1-sharp-box-sports.cloudfunctions.net/api/standings?sport=mlb

And the data url for team stats (which is working properly): https://us-central1-sharp-box-sports.cloudfunctions.net/api/playerStats?gameID=nba.g.2017051110

Comment: What happens when you console.log the values of `row` and `cell`? If anything is undefined here, you should be able to locate it by just printing out your variables' values.

Comment: That's what is so frustrating. If I log table.Rows[0].Cells it returns the array of cells for the first row.  But row.Cells.map comes up as undefined.

Comment: Like @JulienD suggested, through in a debugger to see what `row` is.
Just place in `{ console.log(row) }` before the TableRowColumn component. That would give insight into what's runt there.

Comment: To be more precise, instead of `table.Rows.map((row, idx3) => <TableRow...`, use `table.Rows.map((row, idx3) => {console.log(row); return <TableRow...}`. Or separate these factories into functions that you can debug more easily.

Comment: @JulienD  this is the output of what you suggested: 
[link](https://prnt.sc/fia1vr)

But it looks like the same structure as the one that works (game stats):
[link](https://prnt.sc/fia2ic)

Comment: @KevinSegal can you do the same with `cell`? One possibility is that one of the `cell.Value` is undefined and your `TableRowColumn` component has a check on PropTypes, requiring an object.

Comment: Also you show us one of the `row`s that gets printed, but another one could be undefined, or have undefined .Cells . You need to print out all that to console, not focus on the structure but on the values.

Comment: @JulienD I added a console log below Cells.map, and its actually registering the cell data, but it's coming up as an array - I think this is the issue. So if 'row' is an object, with a cell array within it, how do I loop through the cell array from within a row.map function?

Comment: @JulienD here's log output
`[Log] Object (mlb, line 68)
...
[Log]  error      – TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Cells.map') (mlb, line 68)
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Cells.map')
Object
[Log] s – {login: Object, sportsdata: Object, form: {}, …} (mlb, line 68)
{login: Object, sportsdata: Object, form: {}, dialog: {alertOptions: {}, confirmOptions: {}}}Object
[Log] {Cells: Array} (mlb, line 68)
[Log] {Value: "35"} (mlb, line 68)
[Log] {Value: "23"} (mlb, line 68)
[Log] {Value: ".603"} (mlb, line 68)

`

Comment: @JulienD AHA! Found it. You were right. There's a goddamn item, only one or two per sport, but its stuck between cell arrays, { "IsSeparator": true }.  That solves it.  If you know of any elegant ways of snipping this out of the api response before its fed to the reducer, I'm all ears! lol thank you for your help

Comment: @KevinSegal Glad you found it. Just filter your data before feeding it in: `gameStatsTable = gameStatsTable.filter(...)`. In a modern language, more elegant would be to store the data in an object with a fixed structure (class), which would detect or remove these anomalies automatically. But Javascript sucks in all possible ways, don't even try "elegant".